# Access to ArrayList data in another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, arraylist

I add some data in my **array List**, then I want to use this **array List** data in another **thread**, the problem is when I call the **array List** in new thread, that **array List** is empty and haven't any data that before thread has started.

How Can I access to my **array list** in this case?
And any one know whats the logic of this case?

Comment: Is it possible for you to start the second thread after you have data in your `ArrayList`? Did you try using `LiveData` and `Observers`?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use ArrayList with multiple threads, it is not thread-safe. Instead 
create a synchronized list for it.

```
Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<ClassName>());
```

I suppose your problem is different, are you sure that you are accessing the same ArrayList in both threads? If both threads are pointing the same `ArrayList`, you able to access data in it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried [synchronizedList](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections#synchronizedList(java.util.List%3CT%3E))?

You could do something like:

```
List<String> syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
syncList.add(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));

Runnable runnable = () -> {
    assertThat(syncList.size()).isEqualTo(3);
};

Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();
thread.join();
```